# change body color when slider change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using bootstrap 4 slider. I want to change background color of body when first item is active in the bootstrap slider. and if any other item is active then body color will normal.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlrwv.png)

```css
.carousel-item{ width:100%; height:400px; background-color:red; text-align:center; line-height:400px; font-size:100px; color:#fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<body>
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active"> 1 </div>
    <div class="carousel-item"> 2 </div>
    <div class="carousel-item"> 3 </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span> </a> <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span> </a> </div>
</body>
```

Comment: show your code here

Comment: One can not copy and paste code from images. So images of code are sort of useless.

Comment: Sorry, no. Please place all code in the question. We should not have to go offsite to an untrusted third party domain in order to understand the context of your question.

Comment: sir run code snippet I updated there.

Comment: @ImranAli- u updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the carousel callback

```
$('#demo').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  if(!e.to){
    //set body bgcolor
  }else{
    //remove body bgcolor
  }
});
```

You can find docs here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#events

Comment: but first time its not work.. but when again 1st item active then it work